# Disable "deletion of copy constructor when move constructor is avaliable" on Clang

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, clang++

Looking here on StackOverflow I found out that on Clang++ when using C++11 standard, if you have defined a move constructor to your class, the implicit constructor generation is disabled, i.e. copy constructor is "explicted deleted".

Is there any way to disable this behavior?

Also, is this behavior standardized? Because I don't have the same behavior in GCC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any way to disable this behavior?

No.  But you can always:

```
A(const A&) = default;
```

Though I'm unsure if clang currently fully implements defaulted copy constructors.

> Also, is this behavior standardized?

Yes.  [class.copy]/p7:

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy
>   constructor, one is declared implicitly. If the class definition
>   declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the
>   implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted; ...

...

> Because I don't have the same behavior in GCC.

Which version?  I would've guessed that the latest gcc version had the same behavior as clang.  But I do not have it available to experiment with.

Comment: Clang's support for defaulted functions is at least good enough that they claim to support them on their c++ status page. Usually you guys don't list features for which any substantial work remains to be done.

Comment: What if the move constructor is defined as deleted, will the implicitly declared copy constructor also be defined as deleted?